# Definition of a Semi Algebra

Tags: measure-theory, semialgebras

I am self-studying a book on Measure Theory and Probability Theory by Lahiri and Athreya. I encountered the following definition of a Semi-Algebra.

Let $Ω$ be a nonempty set and let $P(Ω)$ be the power set
of $Ω$. A class $C⊂P(Ω)$ is called a semialgebra if

(i) $A, B \in C \Rightarrow A \cap B \in C $

(ii) For any $A \in C$ there exists sets $B_1, B_2, ..., B_k \in C$ for some $1 \le k \lt \infty$, such that $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$ and $A^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_i$ .

Following that, the book says that it can easily be shown that the smallest algebra containg $C$ is $\mathscr A =$  { $A : A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_i, B_i \in C$ for $i= 1, ... , k, k \lt \infty$ }

My problem is that I cannot seem to show the proof of the theorem. After searching for some other stackexchange questions, there is an additional assumption in the definition.

(iii) $\emptyset \in C$

or (iii') $ Ω \in C$

It seems like this solves the problem because I cannot seem to show that the algebra generated by the semi - algebra does not necessarily contain the empty set and the entire set $Ω$.

My question is, did the book have a mistake in its definition by ommiting an extra assumption or does the third assumption I just stated follow from the two above. If yes, how do you show that one of those I have mentioned are there?

Comment: Your (i) and (jj) are satisfied if $C$ is the empty subclass of $P(\Omega)$, which doesn't seem right. The formula you give for the smallest algebra containing $A$ seems to be garbled: you have $A$ both as a free variable and as a bound variable.

Comment: @RobArthan Arthan I fixed it already.  It should be, "The smallest algebra containing $C$ is $\mathscr A$..."